# Prevent CMD Start command from terminating after completion

Tags: windows, cmd

I have the following CMD script,

```
    @echo off
    set APP_HOME=C:\Temp\Hammer
    rem Set APP_HOME to the place where you installed Hammer.

    if "%~1"=="" (
       echo You must provide a Python script to run.
       pause
    ) else (
       @start /min java.exe -jar %APP_HOME%\lib\bolt.jar
       @start java.exe -cp "%APP_HOME%\lib\jython.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\Hammer.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\gmsecapi.jar;%APP_HOME%\examples\Python;%APP_HOME%\jython2.5.3\Lib;%CLASSPATH%" bridenstine.hammer.main.Main %*
    )
```

After the program, which is executed by the second java.exe command, finishes the terminal closes which prevents the user from reading the outputted text of the program.

I've looked over these [commands](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) but haven't found anything that would keep the window open even after the program ends.

Comment: Are you able to modify the java program to change things there, or do you only want things in your cmd script to be changed in order to solve your problem

Comment: I don't think that the `java` tag is appropriate here. This is only about Windows CMD issues.

Comment: Understood on the Java tag thank you. Doing it in Java might be appropriate but in the future the program might be implemented into a GUI so I thought it would be best to do it in the cmd script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must start the command prompt. You are only starting a console - that's just a window. Preface your commands with `cmd /k`. See `Start /?`.